# How to catch a panic without closing the program

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to catch a panic while the program is running and without closing the program. For example, how to catch a panic here and print “Hello, World”?:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];

    v[99];
    println!("Hello, World");
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `std::panic::catch_unwind` to, well, catch unwinding panics, but do make sure to read [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) first:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let panics = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| v[99]).is_err();
    assert!(panics);
    println!("Hello, World");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know that the index is valid at run time, you can use [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get) instead of `[]` indexing.  This will return an option, either `Some()` if the element exists, or `None` if it does not:

```rust
if let Some(x) = v.get(99) {

}
```

or:

```rust
match v.get(99) {
  Some(x) => {

  },
  None => {
  }
}
```

If this is a more general question and the given snippet is just an example, then the correct answer is you don't -- [panics are not for control flow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html).  If you need to recover from an error, you should use a method that returns a `Result` or `Option`.

Comment: Is panic not for the control flow? I don't understand you. Have link to rust docs?

Comment: Sure, see the link to the rust book section on "to panic or not to panic".  The whole section on Error handling may be useful too.

Comment: This answer doesn't really help unfortunately. If you are using a library which panics when it shouldn't, you only recourse is to totally rewrite that method from scratch. 
It might be simple, or you might have to effectively fork that library and start from the beginning. Its not an answer. We can preach "panics are not for control flow" until we're blue in the face but if no human is listening, its not going to help.